# Is there a quick way to delete all your large files on your Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, file-management

I know how to use the "all my files" thing and sort by size, but it seems that the largest file that appears there is around 1GB. I suspect there is some other way to list all large files (apps, folders whatever). I would like to do that to free some space.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 3):

From Finder:

```
File > Find > Kind > Other > File Size + is greater than 1GB
```

[image]

Terminal (replace dot with the path you want to search for these big files):

```
find . -size +1GB -exec rm -rf {} \;

find . -type f -size +1GB -exec rm -rf {} \; # just for files
```

Answer (score 2):

A great GUI option is called Grand Perspective and can be found [here](http://grandperspectiv.sourceforge.net/). It also shows a tree map of the folder you point it at, which immediately shows you the largest files under the folder.

It's been around since 2008 and is Mavericks-compatible.

Best of all, it's free.

Comment: Just wanted to update that Grand Perspective still works great with 10.13.3 and appears to still be under active development.

Answer (score 1):

Try Disk Inventory X: http://www.derlien.com

It will show you a visual view of your hard drive.

[image]